# How to Add a Method to a Method In a Class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have the following class:

```
import webbrowser

class Management(object):

  def add_accounts(self, data):
    operations = []
    for account_name in data:
      operations.append(
        {'operator': 'ADD',
         'operand': {'name': account_name}
         })
    self.added = operations

manager = Management()
manager.add_accounts(['name 1', 'name 2'])
```

What I want to do is add this function:

```
def source():
  url = r'http://www.stackoverflow.com/some-help-doc'
  webbrowser.open(url, new=1)
```

to the `add_accounts` method so I can type the following:

```
manager.add_accounts.source()
```

and have it open my default browser to the help article online:

I've been searching for how to add a method to an already existing method in a class. Is there a name for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: In Python 3, you can do `Management.add_accounts.source = source`.  It will not be a method of `add_accounts`, it will just be a function stored in an attribute of `add_accounts`.  But why do you want to do that?  What do you gain by making yourself access it that particular way?

Comment: Keep in mind that many things can be done Python, much more than in many other languages and much more than what is smart and helpful.

Comment: I want to do it because I'm working with an API and each method within the class requires a very specific construction of the operations `dict`. I have many methods within the class so being able to pull up the online documentation quickly will be helpful to me. I'm hoping to be able to add `source` within the class instead of outside it.

Answer (score 0):

As @BrenBam pointed out in comments, methods do have attributes and those can be anything, including functions. However, this'll make for some weird un-Pythonic code. If you want this method to show some kind of documentation (as example suggests), it'll be better to just copypaste information to a docstring. Docstring is where everyone expects info to be.

Comment: The entire point of adding this function is so I don't have to copy/paste to go to the documentation.

Comment: I understand. But when someone uses your code, what will they do to get information? They'll type `print(Management.add_accounts.__doc__)`. Just copypaste whatever is on Github into docstring and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the best option for now:

```
import webbrowser

class Management(object):

  def __init__(self):
    Management.add_accounts.source = lambda url='https://github.com/': webbrowser.open(url, new=1)

  def add_accounts(self, data):
    operations = []
    for account_name in data:
      operations.append(
        {'operator': 'ADD',
         'operand': {'name': account_name}
         })
    self.added = operations

manager = Management()
```